# Explain why the following conjecture for $f(x)=[x]+(x-[x])^{[x]}$ is not correct?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

Explain why the following conjectures for $f(x)=[x]+(x-[x])^{[x]}$ are not correct ($x\in(0,\infty)$)

> Conjecture a: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(f(x)-[x])=0.$
>
> Conjecture b: $f$ is uniformly continuous

Thanks.

Comment: $x\mapsto [x]$ is the integer part function?

Comment: What did you try to (dis)prove them?

Comment: I think that the first conjecture is correct!!! because of $0\leq x-[x]<1$

Comment: You need to explain what $[x]$ means. This notation has several different possible meanings, including either the "round to nearest integer" function and the "round down to an integer" function. Which of them is it here?

Comment: Uh, @HenningMakholm is right. I posted my answer assuming it was the integer part of $x$, but if it is the rounding to the nearest integer, my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer assumes that $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$, and therefore $x-[x]\geq 0$, $\forall x\geq 0$.

I think $a$ is false. It seems true, since $0<x-[x]<1$, however, it is not uniformly bounded away from 1. To show it is false, it is enough to show that for every $M>0$ there is at least one $x>M$ such that $(x-[x])^{[x]}>a$, with $a\in (0,1)$ fixed.

Let's say $a=1/2$, and let's pick $x = M+9\sum_{k=1}^n 10^{-k}$. This is means that $x-[x]=0.99...9$, with $k$ 9's after the decimal point. How many do I need? Well, I need

$$
\left(9\sum_{k=1}^n 10^{-k}\right)^M>\frac{1}{2}\\
\Rightarrow 9\sum_{k=1}^n 10^{-k} > \frac{1}{\sqrt[M]{2}}\\
\Rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^n 10^{-k} > \frac{1}{9\sqrt[M]{2}}\\
\Rightarrow\frac{1-\frac{1}{10^{n+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{10}}-1>\frac{1}{9\sqrt[M]{2}}\\
\Rightarrow\frac{10}{9}-\frac{1}{9\cdot 10^n}>1+\frac{1}{9\sqrt[M]{2}}\\
\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{10^n} > -1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[M]{2}}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{10^n} < 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[M]{2}}=\frac{\sqrt[M]{2}-1}{\sqrt[M]{2}}\\
\Rightarrow 10^n > \frac{\sqrt[M]{2}}{\sqrt[M]{2}-1}\\
\Rightarrow n>\log_{10} \frac{\sqrt[M]{2}}{\sqrt[M]{2}-1}.
$$

Clearly, the larger is $M$, the larger is the number of 9's you need to keep to stay above $1/2$, but that's not the point. The set of numbers for which $(x-[x])^{[x]}>1/2$ is unbounded.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to observe that $(x-[x])^{[x]}$ is $0$ when $x$ is a positive integer, but $1/2$ whenever $x=n+\sqrt[n]{1/2}$ for positive integer $n$?

Comment: Uh, that's much more concise. Good remark.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a straight and simple solution?

Comment: What do you mean by 'solution'?